# Including plusone and twitter button in Octopress

Tags: javascript, google-plus, jekyll, google-plus-one, octopress

I own a webpage generated with Octopress. It has a article overview on a main page, which includes the last ten articles. Every article gets a +1 button. But if I +1 one article, the whole page gets +1'd. I don't want that, as you may think.

How do I do that?

Comment: If this is occurring in an Octopress default feature, then it sounds like a bug; perhaps file an issue: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues  Could you link to your Jekyll source code so we may take a closer look?  You haven't provided enough detail to properly answer how to adjust the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template is using the +1 button without setting the "href" parameter documented here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters

Make each button point to the URL of the relevant article.